# Binding Geometry properties in an ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

In a Silverlight game I'm working on I'm using an `ItemsControl` to display an `ObservableCollection` of game objects that we'll call `Foo`. `Foo` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a single property: `Radius`. The `ItemsControl`'s `ItemTemplate` represents each `Foo` as an circular path, with the radius of the path bound to `Foo.Radius`.

The problem I'm running into is that whenever I try to add something to the `ObservableCollection` I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." If a remove the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` bindings program runs fine, and it still works if I bind `Foo.Radius` to some property of `Path`. I'm at a loss for how to bind the geometry properties. Am I missing something?

XAML for reference:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Stroke="Black">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="{Binding Radius}" RadiusY="{Binding Radius}" />
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Codebehind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Foo> things = new ObservableCollection<Foo>();

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = things;
    CompositionTarget.Rendering += Update;
}

void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    things.Add(new Foo());
}
```

Comment: This isn't real code right?  You wouldn't be wanting to add new content everytime a frame is rendered, you'd run out of memory in a few seconds.

Comment: No, this is a simplified version. In the real code there's some logic to decide if a new object should be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more searching and discovered that in Silverlight 3 [it's only possible to bind properties to `FrameworkElement`s](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/03/27/silverlight-3-s-new-element-data-binding.aspx), but `Geometry` inherits from `DependencyObject`. Upgrading the project to Silverlight 4 seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => things.Add(new Foo()));
```

Comment: This will not help, CompositionTarget.Rendering fires on the UI thread.

Comment: its not about dispatching it to the UI thread... its deferring the addition of the new Foo until rendering is finished by using BeginInvoke() .... probably we need a DispatcherPriority of Background.... any thoughts?

Comment: @AngelWPF the Silverlight dispatcher does not support priority like WPF does.

Comment: @ColinE:  I think its worth a try, AngelWPF is right it puts the execution of the Add outside the somewhat weird context of a Frame currently being rendered.

Comment: When I tried this code, it didn't throw an exception inside VS, but IE caught a RuntimeError with the message AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE.

Comment: This is another error due to something else e.g. XAML and code behind do not confirm each other... some event handler from XAML does not exist in the code behind or so ...